# onBlur event runs automatically when loading application ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onblur

I'm working with ReactJS and I need to execute a validation to an input text so I using onBlur but it runs automatically when loading the application.

My code is very simple to the example:

```
onBlur ={ alert() }
```

How can I prevent onBlur from running automatically?

Thanks!

Comment: can you try `onBlur ={(e)=> alert() }`? https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: @Justcode but when I tried **onBlur ={ this.error('lastName') }** to run error method never works :/

Comment: I can not see `(e)` into your code

Comment: I added (e) `onBlur ={ (e)=>this.error }` and the method to try is very simple `error = () =>{
        alert()
    }` but the problem is the same, 
it is executed automatically when loading the application.

Comment: try -   `onBlur = {this.alert}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yo just need to give the function name there and on blur react will execute this function.
so you need to write this:-

```
onBlur ={ alert }
```

edit based on the comment,
The code which you have posted should have the same behavior, you can put a console.log in the error function, I am sure it will get called, providing you are not getting any error.

now I guess you want to pass some data in the callback and that's why going with this approach,
to achieve the same you can use

```
onBlur ={ ()=>{this.error('lastName');} }
```

Comment: I tried: **onBlur ={ this.error('lastName') }** but never run the event

Comment: Thanks man this is the code:

`onBlur ={ this.error('lastName') }`

Comment: `error = (nameInput) =>{
        let form = {...this.state.form};
        return form[nameInput].value !== '' ? !form[nameInput].valid : null;
    }`

Comment: @OscarDev i have updated the code, follow that i am sure it will work for you.
good luck